# jQuery appending double quote doesn't work properely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that I want to append dynamic elements inside , these elements are just divs that have specific classes , and some custom attribute called tag , the function works fine , but for some elements it just acts weird , here is an example : 
to append a div that will show operator "=" , and have tag attribute equal to "" , i use :

```
$("#Add_equal").click(function(){
    $("#rule_assembly").append('<div tag="<equal></equal>" class="block operator">=</div>')
```

and it works fine.

to use same algorithm to append a div that will show operator "/" , and have tag attribute equal to "" , i use:

```
 $("#rule_assembly").append('<div tag="<expr operator="/"></expr>" class="block mathoperator">/</div>')
```

this one doesn't work it is supposed to show "/" but it doesnt !! any help would be appreciated .

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/eQYdn/

try pressing equal button , and division button.

Comment: your attribute is invalid, it's wrapped in double quotes and contains double quotes.

Comment: `$("#rule_assembly").append('<div tag="<expr operator=\'/\'></expr>" class="block mathoperator">/</div>')`  http://jsfiddle.net/eQYdn/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your attribute is invalid, it's wrapped in double quotes and contains double quotes. You must escape the inner quotes.

```
'<div tag="<expr operator=&quot;/&quot;></expr>" class="block mathoperator">/</div>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eQYdn/3/

Comment: @ProllyGeek because there is no wrapped quotes inside tag attribute here

Comment: because `<equal></equal>` doesn't contain double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some weirdness going on with your single and double quotes so the string is concatenating incorrectly. Try the following for the / div instead of what you've got:

```
 $("#rule_assembly").append('<div tag="<expr operator=' + '/' + '></expr>" class="block mathoperator">/</div>');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: this doesn't do the required function , inspect the appended div , and check tag attribute.